# Translation of words stubborn and obstinate

Tags: word-meaning, vocabulary

I'd like to find a word, which will express better such a human quality: when you work hard to achieve a goal not paying attention to any obstacles, and when you can't leave a task before finishing it.

I would say something like stubbornness or obstinacy describes it, but I'm not sure whether these words can be used in such a meaning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for words to describe the quality of "work[ing] hard to achieve a goal not paying attention to any obstacles, and when you can't leave a task before finishing it."

You can look up the dictionary definition of these words, but I might suggest:

- Driven
- Dogged
- Ambitious
- Persistent
- Determined
- Undeterred